# Is there a relationship between voltage and State of Charge of a NiCd battery?

Tags: batteries, battery-charging

When a NiCd battery is charged, it can go above it's nominal voltage per cell of 1.2 V, typically up to 1.5 V per cell.

How fast does this voltage go down to its nominal voltage if no load is connected?

Comment: There technically is, but it's not a good one to use. Not very reliable. It's nonlinear, but that's not why it isn't reliable. You need to google "discharge curve".

Answer (score 1):

Yes it can be driven above its 1.5V per cell, but that will damage it. How much above depends on the current you are forcing into the battery. The charge rate for a NiCad is right between 1.2 V and 1.45 V per cell. When not under load or charge, a Ni–Cd battery will self-discharge approximately 10% per month at 20 °C, ranging up to 20% per month at higher temperatures. It is possible to perform a trickle charge at current levels just high enough to offset this discharge rate; to keep a battery fully charged. This is affected by both battery condition and storage temperature. Try this link:
https://www.batterystuff.com/kb/articles/battery-articles/what-the-heck-is-a-nicd-battery.html

Answer (score 0):

NiCd's ought to obsolete due to the Cadmium pollution in landfills...

All e-caps and batteries have "some" memory effects due to the "double-layer capacitance" effects in how they operate.  NiCd's were notoriously worse although very high density.  That means there is a secondary capacitance in parallel but with a high time constant so after a momentary discharge even to 0V  they resume back with the secondary charges.  This memory effect makes it have hysteresis for any voltage if there were an unknown Charge and Discharge recently. So V vs SoC is not always a reliable method, but it can be if know the history, internal ESR if drawing current or allow suitable resting time for the secondary charge layer to equalize..